# Order of Array Elements?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I defined my array like:

```
$data1 = array(
            'first_name'=>$this->input->post('first_name'),  
            'last_name'=>$this->input->post('last_name'),
            'company'=>$this->input->post('company'),
            'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
            'phone'=>$phonenum,
            'username'=>strtolower($this->input->post('first_name')) . ' ' . strtolower($this->input->post('last_name'))
```

This array was sent from a controller to a model in CodeIgniter. When I tried to use array_splice to remove the email and username, couldn't get it to remove the right elements. When checked it with xdebut, the order had changed to:

username
email
first_name
last_name
company

Can anyone tell me why? Thanks.
phone

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove email and username just do it ;

```
unset($data1['email']);
unset($data1['username']);
```

Comment: I'll remember that next time. Thanks.